# Changing colour of square issue

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone can help me. I'm trying to change the colour of my square at the bottom of my homepage it keeps on disappearing when I attempt to change the colour. I'm trying to change it to the colour white from solid red. Why does this keep happening?

[Here is my codepen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/dNKpEg)

Below is my CSS coding.

```
.next {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left:50%;
  cursor:pointer;  
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  border: 4px solid red;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Kind Regards,

Liam

Comment: change `border: 4px solid red;` to `border: 4px solid white;`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your css the arrow shape and color is set with the `border` property. In this case it's the right and bottom borders of your div that are given a red border, then the div is rotated to look like an arrow pointing downwards.

**Update the border color to white instead of red:**

```
border: 4px solid white;
```

If you were already doing the above, check in the developer console. Sometimes codepen doesn't fully update with your changes -- reload the page to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using specifying the color as a hex value?

```
 border: 4px solid #ff0000; //red
```